# Is it possible to install GeoServer On Google Cloud?

Tags: geoserver, installation, google, cloud-gis, google-cloud

How can I can install [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/) on [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/)?

Answer (score 6):

It can be done by using a pre-defined [Geoserver Docker container](https://github.com/kartoza/docker-geoserver).

Investing the time to [learn Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/) is really worthwhile as it allows you to stand up and replace your cloud Geoserver instances very quickly. Adding to the Dockerfile will also allow you configure Geoserver automatically with your workspaces, data sources and layers.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I've read up on this being possible, at least through the OpenGEO Suite which is offered by Boundless Geo which packages Geoserver as part of their stack. I came across this release from [Boundless Geo](http://boundlessgeo.com/products/opengeo-suite/) that mentions [GeoMesa's](http://www.geomesa.org/) collaboration and efforts to provide geospatial analysis and leverage Geoserver for spatial processing on Google Cloud.

You could read up more [here](http://boundlessgeo.com/2015/05/google-geoserver-support-geospatial-big-data-cloud/) on the announcement

Comment: Thanks whyzar,
But can you please tell me steps for  installing Geo Server on my Google cloud Instance ?

Comment: [Penn State](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog865/node/7) has an explanation on how to get it up and running on AWS.

Comment: Thanks MDHald, But i am not using AWS i have an Google Cloud Account on [https://console.developers.google.com] and i want to Install Geo Server here not on AWS.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install tomcat on it, then use tomcat to install Geoserver Web Archive.

use https://bitnami.com/stack/tomcat/cloud/google to install tomcat,
then follow this video to install geoserver
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEOA8WWWVCw

Comment: Hello @muke, thanks for all the links.
When I try importing geoserver.war on my tomcat i got 
"Bad Gateway
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server."

Please can you help me?